# Vue & Quasar: How to read a file (zip) which is outside the quasar project

Tags: vue.js, quasar

I am very new in Vue and Quasar. 
So, i am trying to read-load a file inside a vue page and especially in the script section inside a  mounted () block.

I have tried to load the file using the following:

> var baseL = require('../assets/congressL.zip');

However i got back the following error:

> Failed to compile.

./src/assets/congressL.zip 1:2
Module parse failed: Unexpected character '' (1:2)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type, currently no loaders are configured to process this file. See https://webpack.js.org/concepts#loaders
(Source code omitted for this binary file)

I have tried also to just put the actual path of the file like:

> var baseL = 'congressL.zip'
>   But vue cannot find the file.

Do you have any idea of how to solve this?
Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

As I know The Error Shown is Absolutely Right Because Vue can not understand Files with .zip extension. It can not only understand .js and .vue extension files.

So if you wanted to compile this file by vue you need to First Extract that zip file and It will not show Error if File You have specified haveabove mentioned two Extensions.

So please Learn Something about how Vue works and which files it accepts.

Answer (score 0):

thanks for your answer, i know that vue cannot understand zip files, for this reason i was trying to find a webpack loader which will allow me to pass it (zip file) in as a buffer. However, i did not manage to find something.